# Connect to Avaya Database

Tags: avaya

i try to connect to avaya database to get data from it , how ? 
i`m .net developer and try to develope program to generate some report "life reports".

please help me :(

Answer (score 4):

Hamdy,

If you mean Avaya CMS for call center statistics, then you can connect to it with ODBC to get historical data. To do that, you need to have your CMS administrator install ODBC software server side, as described in document called "Avaya Call Management System ODBC and JDBC" that you can get here: http://support.avaya.com/css/Products/P0030/Application%20&%20Technical%20Notes#. Make sure to choose the right version in "Release" drop-down control on that page, because there were changes in ODBC installation procedures between CMS versions. When ODBC is installed and configured, you can get access to historical and dictionary tables on CMS.
If you need to access real time data, then I suggest to talk to Avaya representative. Key words are Generic-RTA and RT_Socket, these are two real time data interfaces used by most applications out there. They're not free though and do not come as standard with CMS, this is why you need to engage Avaya to obtain them.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Alex.